# Exclude menu background image on responsive versions

Tags: css, wordpress

i am working on a wordpress site and would like to Use a custom CSS, to add a background image behind my menu? and would like to know how to add dividers to the menu so that there is a divider automatically generated after each link item on the menu?

what i did is

```
.menu{
  background-image: url("abolutepath/header-navigation-bar-bg.png"); 
 }
```

---

and it works, the menu and background displays, But the problems are a. the curved end of the menu background doesn't show on the right as the menu ends midway, i want to show the whole background image as is under the menu b. on mobile device the menu is repeated and displays all wrong  so is there a way I can exclude this background image and the dividers from the responsive version of the menu/site all in one block of css code?

Please help, thanks

Comment: maybe some example code? or example on codepen etc

Answer (score 0):

REgarding, how to add dividers to the menu 
You can add to anchor tag in li

```
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
```

and remove border from last menu like below :-

```
li:last-child a {border-right: none;}
```

To add image, try below :-

```
#nav li + li {
    background:url('seperator.gif') no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: 10px
}
```

Comment: Thanks Khushboo, this works except the height of the lines added is bigger than my menu, anyway of reducing the height or even better yet using the image of a line to create the divider?

Comment: You can give background image to li and set it to left using padding. And remove the image from last li using li:last-child

Comment: ok please elaborate, what i had done was .menu li{border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  
} and it worked and i got the lines i wanted but the problem was the height of the divider lines, the height was bigger than the menu, so how can i reduce this height or alternatively how can i replace the divider line with an image of a line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to customize css as per device scren size

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .menu{
        // CSS for mobile device or small screen size
        background-image: url("abolutepath/header-navigation-bar-bg.png"); 
    }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 960px) {
    .menu{
        // CSS for other device
    }
}
```

Comment: @user54779 Fine, Just set `background:none` within `@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {` code block. It won't appear in mobile devices then.